# Trading View API and Interactive Broker Connection for Automatic trades

Tags: api, connection, interactive-brokers

I've created a trading bot on Trading View. I need to learn how to connect Trading View to Interactive Brokers for executing trades.

How do you connect Trading View to Interactive Broker via the Trading View API?

CHAT GPT sent me to Trading View's Stack OverFlow.

Answer (score 1):

TradingView only provides a Strategy Tester for backtesting a strategy on historical data. It does not allow for live execution of trading strategies.
https://www.tradingview.com/support/solutions/43000481026-how-to-autotrade-using-pine-script-strategies/

If you are interested in running your strategy on live data, unfortunately you will have to re-write that strategy to integrate with the API that your broker provides. Interactive Brokers has their own here.
https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/trading/ib-api.php

Comment: Hi Josh, thanks for answering my question. Time saver to get that sorted.

Answer (score 0):

To connect TradingView to Interactive Brokers for executing trades, you need to generate webhook messages and send them to a webserver's public endpoint.

For example, I used [this PineScript](https://www.tradingview.com/script/xOO4qW1P-PineTradingbotWebhook/) library that enables the generation of JSON webhook messages.

Once the webserver receives the webhook messages, it parses the information and proceeds to place orders using either the TWS API or the IB Insync API.

There are multiple Docker files available to quickly verify this setup. [The specific Docker file](https://github.com/PlusGenie/ib-gateway-docker) I utilized for this purpose is as follows: